# Posting 'object' to WebApi works, but ViewModel comes in null, and string throws up a big mess

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I send "TargetViewModel" down using WebAPI (v2.2). At the top of the ViewModel I have [JsonObject] and this now works OK: I get my object down to the client and it renders fine.

However, I want to send the object back. So I've got a Post method in my ApiController-derived controller. The method starts:

```
    [Route]
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public DataPostResponse Post(TargetViewModel PostBack)
    {
```

If I post to this I get a null object.

If I change "TargetViewModel" in the method signature to simply 'object' I get a populated object. Same if I use JObject as the type.

If I change "TargetViewModel" to type 'string' I instead get: No action was found on the controller that matches the request...

... but there is, because it finds it when it's set to 'TargetViewModel' or 'object'.

So I was wondering why this might be.

Comment: Can you post your TargetViewModel class here? And JavaScript where you do POST to this method.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. After hours of looking in the wrong place I finally found it was because TargetViewModel didn't have a parameterless constructor. Thanks anyway, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else having this kind of issue, here's how I found out what was going on:

I tried changing the method signature to expect a JObject instead and then later on de-serialize it to my complex ViewModel.  This then threw up the error that was the root of it all: No parameterless constructor existed for my Complex View Model. A silly mistake, but I was going around for hours on this one until I finally got an error that pointed me in the right direction.

Always check you have a parameterless constructor.